# How inform the maven dependency point to .m2 without close the project

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, m2e

my project consist of 3 module project, they are pom, war and jar.

jar.menu.service----jar,
menu -----war,
pom.menu.app ---pom.

[photo helps describe the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP9tn.jpg)

when project jar.menu.service still open, jar.menu.service will become a folder under maven dependencies. If I click 'run on server' for menu project, error come due to can't find some files. See PHOTO 2

when project jar.menu.service closed manually, jar.menu.service will become a jar under maven dependencies. If I click 'run on server' for menu project, it works.  See PHOTO 3

The question is that can I keep jar.menu.service open and jar.menu.service still exist in a jar under maven dependencies.

Under current situation, I cannot perform code development by debug the project in server on eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project, choose "Maven -> Disable Workspace Resolution".

Workspace resolution allows you to directly reference open projects in the workspace. If you don't want that, disable it.